# using 'at' command in a bash file

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I would like to create a command `alarm` which plays a song at a given time. Here is the bash file, `alarm`, I've unfortunately created:

```
#!/bin/bash

at $1
open /.../mysongs/sweetsong.mp3
```

but when I run `alarm 0830` in my terminal, a job is created and the song immediately starts playing. Then when the time actually comes for the job to run, nothing happens. I've come to the conclusion that it comes down to my use of `at`. Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `man at`:

> The  at utility shall read commands from standard input and group them together as an at-job, to be executed at a later time.

So you need to pass the command in to standard input (and [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)):

```
at "$1" < 'open /.../mysongs/sweetsong.mp3'
```